# Load webview into viewpager by replacing imageview in the view pager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager, lazy-loading, android-imageview

i am implementing an app in which i firstly load images into viewpager. I need to replace the images and get webview after it loads completely. how can i do it.

My viewpager code is as follows:

```
public class HtmlPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<LinearLayout> views;

    Context con;


    public HtmlPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LinearLayout> filelist) {
        this.con = context;

        views = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

        this.views = filelist;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View view, int arg1, Object object) {

        ((ViewPager) view).removeView((LinearLayout) object);


    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {

        View myView = views.get(position);
        ((ViewPager) view).addView(myView);

        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {

    }
}
```

my imageview creation code is as like as follows:

```
for(int t=0;t<list.length;t++){
            ImageView img=new ImageView(con);   // con is context
            img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            line = new LinearLayout(con);
            img.setBackgroundResource(drawable.bg_downissue);
            line.addView(img);
            filelist.add(line);       //filelist is arraylist<linearlayout>
        }
            adapter = new HtmlPagerAdapter(con, filelist);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My webview creation is also a dynamic webview like

```
for(int t=0;t<list.length;t++){
WebView web=new WebView(this);
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(myUrl);
}
```

i want to place this webview into the imageview in viewpager. Please help me. I am really stuck on this part.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change quite a bit of those code:

change the ImageView and WebView creation to a XML layout, put both inside a FrameLayout with match_parent.

On the WebView you'll attach a [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and override the onPageFinished to know when the page finished loading.

Then it's just a matter of inflating the XML and make the WebView invisible; then whenever the WebViewClient notifies that it finished loading you set the WebView visible and the ImageView invisible.